# Geom_spoke not plotting properly

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the length and angle of a bursting event for a marine animal. However, I dont think it is plotting properly. The event occurring at 75m has an ascent of 31 however this is not translating to the graph.

Further, I was wanting to cut the x-axis between 75 & 95.

```
ggplot(depth, aes(y=hour, x= Startdepth,)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = Pitchavg, radius = ascent), size = 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#E7B800","#FC4E07",  "#00AFBB", '#004E54')) +
  annotate("rect", ymin = 5, ymax = 8.5, xmin = -1, xmax = 100,
           alpha = .1, fill = "blue") +
  annotate("rect", ymin = 16.5, ymax = 21.5, xmin = -1, xmax =100,
           alpha = .1, fill = "blue") +
  ylim(0, 24)
```

[image: Geom_spoke output]

Below is a sample of my data:

```
Shark   Startdepth  Pitchavg      ascent    Hour
3       5.84887     15.170846     3.34844     19
4       0.424778    -1.737293333  0.014004    22
5       4.1233       7.2578775    0.02645     19
5       4.95108     17.91744      1.07518     19
5       4.77525     23.388734     0.95225     20
6       5.57968    -20.51986667   0           22
6      10.3285      37.778        4.48275      0
6       6.73732     17.5535036    5.52834      1
6       7.01584     27.8316       2.28104      1
6       0.977145   -24.41713333   0            4
6      55.3021      31.6784       9.9084      15
7       8.04433     24.8095       0           10
7      18.712       45.95876667   0           10
7      17.3225      26.36621125  16.374918    10
7      14.0488      37.84178571   0           11
7      20.24        35.13114667   0           11
7      25.5022       9.78095025   2.4459      13
```

Comment: You forgot the color aesthetic. If it maps to column `depthclass`, then you also forgot that column in your sample data.

Comment: The colour depthclass has been removed from the script so the data not being there isn't an issue. Do you know why it is not plotting my data correctly>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `geom_spoke` accepts `angle` in radians and you have angles in degrees. Convert radians to degrees in `aes` and the plot seems right.

I have commented out the `scale_color_*` since the variable mapping to color was removed from the data, as said in the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195279/geom-spoke-not-plotting-properly?noredirect=1#comment127593350_72195279).

```r
x <- 'Shark   Startdepth  Pitchavg      ascent    Hour
3       5.84887     15.170846     3.34844     19
4       0.424778    -1.737293333  0.014004    22
5       4.1233       7.2578775    0.02645     19
5       4.95108     17.91744      1.07518     19
5       4.77525     23.388734     0.95225     20
6       5.57968    -20.51986667   0           22
6      10.3285      37.778        4.48275      0
6       6.73732     17.5535036    5.52834      1
6       7.01584     27.8316       2.28104      1
6       0.977145   -24.41713333   0            4
6      55.3021      31.6784       9.9084      15
7       8.04433     24.8095       0           10
7      18.712       45.95876667   0           10
7      17.3225      26.36621125  16.374918    10
7      14.0488      37.84178571   0           11
7      20.24        35.13114667   0           11
7      25.5022       9.78095025   2.4459      13'
depth <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(depth, aes(x = Startdepth, y = Hour)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = Pitchavg * pi/180, radius = ascent), size = 1) +
  #scale_color_manual(values = c("#E7B800","#FC4E07",  "#00AFBB", '#004E54')) +
  annotate("rect", ymin = c(5, 16.5), ymax = c(8.5, 21.5), xmin = c(-1, -1), xmax = c(100, 100),
           alpha = 0.1, fill = "blue") +
  ylim(0, 24) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>